# How to add category id css class on body [Magento2]

Tags: magento2

I am trying to add a category id to css class on body tag but not able to find any way to do that.

With that category id on body class I can use different images for each category breadcrumbs using css.

At this moment I can't use default Magento 2 body classes because my website is multi language.

That example how than need to looks like.

```
<body class="current-category-id">
```

Answer (score 1):

Create "after" plugin on \Magento\Catalog\Controller\Category\View::execute method

```
public function afterExecute(
    \Magento\Catalog\Controller\Category\View $subject, 
    \Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultInterface $result
) {
    $result->getConfig()->addBodyClass('current-category-' . $subject->getRequest()->getParam('id'));
}
```

Plase pay attention that Magento already have add uniqu body class to all categories in format:

```
->addBodyClass('categorypath-' . $this->categoryUrlPathGenerator->getUrlPath($category))
->addBodyClass('category-' . $category->getUrlKey());
```